# How to store multiple values of one property in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, types, structure

I am storing informaion about Films in a MySQL database. I want every film to have its Genre. However, a film could have more than one value for Genre (e.g. "Action" and "Comedy"). What is the best way to store such information? Is it a good idea to create 2 tables: one with films (columns: "Title", "Year", etc.) and one with Genre? How would the Genre table look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you need three tables to create a many-to-many relation, one for the films, one for the genres and one for the relation.

For example:

```
Table film:
- id (PRIMARY)
- name
- year
- ....

Table genre:
- id (PRIMARY)
- name

Table film_genre:
- id_film (PRIMARY)
- id_genre (PRIMARY)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @m4 . Would it still optimal if I had like 2000 films and 20 different genres?

Comment: Yes, the primary key automatically adds an index to the tables, so you don't need to worry about performance (at least with only 2000 films and 20 genres).

Answer (score 0):

Logically genres are static data. In such case you can store multiple values in one field. For this you need only 2 tables.
Films (dynamic) and Genres(static).

Table Genres will have only 2 fields:

```
- name
- bit
```

So Genres table will have predefined static data like:

```
Comedy - 1
Horror - 2
Action - 4
Porn - 8
Dram - 16
```

Table Films should look like:

```
- i_film
- name
- year
- genre
- ...
```

And in field `Films`.genre you need to store genres as a bit mask.

For example:

genre = 4 means that this film is Action

genre = 5 - genre is Action and Comdey

genre = 7 - genre is Action, Horror and Comedy

genre = 9 - genre is Porn and Comedy

etc

To get Films by genre you can easily:

```
  SELECT * FROM Films WHERE (genre & 8) > 0  - all Porn films
  SELECT * FROM Films WHERE (genre & 1) > 0  - all Comdey films
```

Comment: How would you then do a query based on genres?

Comment: Genre is a static. So Porn bit will be always 8
So to get porn films:
Select * from Films WHERE (genre & 8) > 0

Comment: As you said, bitwise is an option when the data is static, but think the complexity to add new genres in the future (an yes, stuff that seem to be static perhaps were dynamic in the future).

Comment: True, it will be useful only if data is static. But Genre of film is static. Is not it ?))

Comment: And if you want to add some extra genre, that was not present previously also very easy. Add one more genre to Genres table with appropriate bit and use it

Comment: Adding new Genres seems to be kind of complicated anyway. For example, If I want to  add Thriller as a new Genre, I have to think of all the combinations with previous genres? E.g Film that action, drama and thriller is different to action, thriller or drama, thriller. So to add one Genre I have many many combinations to add. Right @PavelZdarov.?

Comment: Not really. Film that action, drama and thriller will have genre as SUM of bits of each genre. Thats why static table Genre has bits like 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128.. each bit corresponds to specific genre. Binary it will look like, 00000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000, 00010000, etc.. Thats why it called bit mask. and you need just to use logical operator like AND, OR , XOR to work with it. 

if you have Film1 - "action" and "drama" = 20 (binary 00010100)
and you have Film2  - "action" and "Porn" = 12 (binary 00001100)

both films are ACTION because they both contain action bit

Comment: If you want to add extra genre to Genres table, you just need to assign this new genre with some bit which is not used yet. If film contains ALL genres -> 11111111111 all bits are set. Hope I was clear) btw you can learn more about bit mask logic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: Bitwise fields in SQL are *really bad*.  They have all the drawbacks of wide, denormalized tables with none of the benefits.  "WHERE (genre & 8) > 0" is a table scan for every lookup!

If a film has multiple genres, just put multiple rows in the film_genre table.  Simple.

Comment: All in all, 3 tables seems to be a less complicated and easier way. Are there any advantages of using Bitwise fields over the 3 tables?

Comment: I agree, 3 tables is easer and probably more correct way. Not sure about performance. But in case if you have a lot of different static data,  I would use bitwise. Cause you can have only 1 table (put static data not in DB but in code as hash array key => value(bit)) and not 3 tables. It depends on a logic of your application and how you gonna use this data.